# Enviar notificaciones con mysql,php y android studio

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, push-notification

Estoy creando una app y necesito que después en mi response de volley envie notificación a otro usuario registrado en una base de datos mysql, que ya se activo su cuenta. Estoy utilizando scrip de php para hacer consultas query a mysql.Aqui se muestra el response en donde al finalizar el registro esta pueda enviar una notificacion a ese usuario, todo con mysql, php, y android studio

```
public void actualizar(String id,String op,String fi,String ff)
{

    StringRequest stringRequest1=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,host+"/webservice/archivos/ejemploBDRemota/opadm.php?", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se registro",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"NO se puedo registrar"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        //--------------------

        Map<String, String> params=new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id",id);
        params.put("opcion",op);
        params.put("fechainicial",fi);
        params.put("fechafinal",ff);


        return params;
    }};
    request.add(stringRequest1);
}
```

Comment: Publica tu código, no una imagen. ¿Cual es la dificultad que enfrentas?

Comment: Necesito enviar notificaciones mediante el id registrado en mi base de datos MYSQL. Sin utilizar firebase. En caso de que se deba de utilizar  pues aplicaria el codigo para enviar notificaciones. Obviamente El usuario ya registrado se le enviara la notificacion aun que su telefono este en reposo. En el response  necesito que hay desde hay envie la notificacion al id correspondiente